# Ionic 2 : Cannot resolve all parameters for

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I've been trying to use a Service on multiple pages, but it works on 1 page out of 2.
Here's my service :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import { DataService } from '../../db/db'

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

constructor(@Inject(SQLite) public db = new SQLite(), public nav: NavController) {
}
```

Here are my attempts to use it :
here it works :

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    providers: [DataService]
})

export class HomePage {
    constructor(public data: DataService){
        this.data = data;
        this.data.results;
    }
}
```

there it doesn't :

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core'
import { DataService } from '../../../db/db'

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'infos.html',
    providers: [DataService]
})

export class NewEnigme {
    constructor(@Inject(DataService) public data: DataService){
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

And tells me

> 'Can't resolve all parameters for NewEnigme: (?).'

Here's my app.module.ts :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    CameraPage,
    DocPage,
    MapPage,
    TabsPage,
    ScannerPage,
    HomePage,
    NewEnigme,
    TabsNewEnigme,
    detailPic
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    CameraPage,
    DocPage,
    MapPage,
    TabsPage,
    ScannerPage,
    TabsNewEnigme,
    detailPic,
    HomePage,
    NewEnigme
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, ConnectivityService, DataService, SQLite]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I've tried everything I could find on Internet and I'm pretty lost here.
I'm new to this, I'd appreciate some help :)

### Edit with more detail (taken from an answer)

If i add one of these functions in my DataService :

```
launchEnigme(par){

    this.nav.push(TabsPage,{
        firstPassed: par.nom,
    });
}

newEnigme(){
    this.nav.setRoot(TabsNewEnigme, {});
}
```

The error occurs.

> Can't resolve all parameters for InfoEnigme: (?).

Full file :

```
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular'
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {SQLite} from 'ionic-native';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs'
import { TabsNewEnigme } from '../new/tabs/newTabs'

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
public results: Array<Object>;

constructor(@Inject(SQLite) public db = new SQLite(), public nav: NavController) {

    console.log("leqdl501");
    db.openDatabase({
        name: 'database.db',
        location: 'default',
        androidDatabaseImplementation: 2// the location field is required
    }).then(() => {
        db.executeSql("drop table if exists Enigmes", {});
        db.executeSql("create table Enigmes(nom VARCHAR(32), description VARCHAR(128))", {});
        db.executeSql("INSERT INTO Enigmes (nom, description) VALUES ('Enquete dans Rouen', 'enquete dans Rouen')", {});
        db.executeSql("INSERT INTO Enigmes (nom, description) VALUES ('Enquete dans Nantes', 'enquete dans Nantes')", {});
        db.executeSql("INSERT INTO Enigmes (nom, description) VALUES ('Enquete dans Paris', 'enquete Parisienne')"
            , {}).then(() => {
            console.log('CREATED');
            this.refresh();
        }, (err) => {
            console.error('Unable to execute sql: ', err);
        });
    }, (err) => {
        console.error('Unable to open database: ', err);
    });
}

refresh() {
    this.db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Enigmes", {}).then((data) => {
        this.results = [];
        if (data.rows.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                this.results.push({
                    nom: data.rows.item(i).nom,
                    description: data.rows.item(i).description
                });

            }
        }
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });

}

launchEnigme(par){

    this.nav.push(TabsPage,{
        firstPassed: par.nom,
    });
}

newEnigme(){
    this.nav.setRoot(TabsNewEnigme, {});
}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a circular reference between your DataService and Page preventing them from correctly instantiating.

This example has the circular reference and **does not work**

https://plnkr.co/edit/HLsphY5ZswHCIAOHcCJr

```
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

import {AlternativePage} from '../../alternative.page';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    public data = 'Data from service';

    constructor(private nav: NavController) { }

    public serviceNavigate() {
      this.nav.push(AlternativePage);
    }

}
```

Without the circular reference your code should work - try and find an alternative solution for your logic.

https://plnkr.co/edit/sdLPz90fTB2jEMGAiILQ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for caring. Already tried, It doesn't change anything on the issue.

Comment: The following plunkr I think does what you are trying to achieve, it does not have the nav controller in the data service or the providers in the components. Check that your filepaths for the import are also correct. https://plnkr.co/edit/sdLPz90fTB2jEMGAiILQ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for taking time @0mpurdy , but this is exactly what i got. I think the problem might be that I handle 2 tabsViews in my app and that seems to f*k up everything

Comment: I got what's wrong. Looks like the error occurs when I invoke nav.push() in my service (or one of my service's methods). Do you have a clue why ?

Comment: @N.R sorry I do not yet have enough reputation to comment on your answer. I was able to replicate the error in this plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/HLsphY5ZswHCIAOHcCJr I think it is because you have a circular reference to the page in the service and the service in the page. I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @Ompurdy Hey sorry for late answer, I slept on it and eventually dissociated nav.push from the data service. Now it works but I still don't know why it doesn't accept View pushing in the Service..

Comment: @N.R I think it is because there is a circular reference (as explained in the answer above) so when your DataService is being created it tries to create your NewEnigme page, which then in it's constructor tries to inject a DataService, which has not yet been created because it requires a NeWEnigme page, so the creation of both fails and you get an error for one of them.